# kentico upgrade issue from version 10 to 11

Tags: kentico

I upgraded my kentico web application project from version 10 to 11 using upgrade installer and used the codeupgrade utility to detect the code issue and modify them.
compiled with

I got a message of successful upgrade.

When I accessed my website locally, got the error message below

```
`Server Error in '/' Application.
An item with the same key has already been added.
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the 
  current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information 
  about the error and where it originated in the code. 

   Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key 
   has already been added.

   Source Error: 


 Line 23: 
  Line 24:         // Initialize CMS application. This method should not be 
 called from custom code.
 Line 25:         InitApplication();
 Line 26:     }
 Line 27: 

   Source File: C:\compass_build\CMS\Global.asax.cs    Line: 25
```

---

Could you please assist me to fix the issue, thanks

Comment: Did you have the code upgrade tool fix the problems for you automatically?  Also, how much custom code do you have?  Did you resolve the custom code problems on your own or with the code upgrade tool?  

The error message you provide could be 1 of 100 or 1000 different issues.  You need to provide more information on your install and custom code.

Comment: Thanks Brenden for your comments.

Comment: I used code upgrade too to fix the code automatically and resolved some issues.

Comment: thanks kentico suppor email to point out only one global.ascx.cs file inside the project. and my solution includes 2, so I removed one of the global.ascx.cs file. then the issue solved.

Comment: Do you mean global.ASAX.cs?
Similar issue but in Kentico 12. Also, I searched for global.asax.cs file and there is only one. There is no global.ascx.cs file in project at all.

Answer (score 1):

thanks kentico suppor email to point out that only one global.ascx.cs file allowed inside the project. 
and my solution includes 2, so I removed one of the global.ascx.cs file. 
then the issue solved.